# Reading Project Metadata from JetBrains IntelliJ ".idea" Directory

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am looking for information/documentation about reading project information from the `.idea` directory within projects created with various JetBrains programmes.

In NetBeans it's fairly straightforward: you open `nbproject/project.xml` and can get the name of the project, as well as the project type (e.g. `org.netbeans.modules.php.project`).

With `.idea`, I am having a harder time finding the definitive locations of the data.

Specifically, I am looking for:

1. Name of the project (if different from root directory name)
2. Exact software the project was created with (WebStorm vs. PhpStorm vs. PyCharm vs. RubyMine vs. [...])

Comment: Have you actually tried a full-text search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Name of the project (if different from root directory name)

Look in `.idea/.name` file (if exists) -- it's a plain text file with single line of text.

> Exact software the project was created with (WebStorm vs. PhpStorm vs. PyCharm vs. RubyMine vs. [...])

There is no such info inside AFAIK -- all products use the same folder/format (well, IntelliJ can also use `.ipr` files IIRC -- [legacy format](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/managing-projects-under-version-control.html#d167791e56)).

Different IDEs may use different types of modules: e.g. PhpStorm/WebStorm only uses `WEB_MODULE` -- look in `.iml` file.

Comment: Great point re. the modules and using them to attempt to derive the respective software.

Comment: @JDR Depending on a module type it might be a very wild guess .. as `WEB_MODULE` can be used by any product -- PhpStorm/WebStorm/PyCharm/RubyMine/IntelliJ. Use `File | New Project` and create one for (lets say) "Twitter Bootstrap" or "Foundation" -- there will be no hints what IDE have created it (unless you will also be judging by other files in `.idea` folder that may appear (more likely) in certain IDE (e.g. references to Java/Python/Ruby SDKs or other language-specific stuff)).